# How can I force the position of an element in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, position, adapter, items

I have an Activity, which simply consists in listing `Pair<String, String>` objects. I have a custom `TextWithSubTextAdapter`, which extends ArrayAdapter:

> public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
>   {
>
> ```
>   View view;
>   if (convertView == null)
>   {
>
>       LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>
>       view = li.inflate(R.layout.text_sub, null);
>
>       TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
>       tv.setText(mCategories.get(position).first);
>
>       TextView desc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subText);
>       desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(mCategories.get(position).second));
>
>
>   }
>   else 
>   {
>       view = (View) convertView;
>   }
>   return view;
> ```
>
> }

mCategories is an `ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>`

I then call `lv.setAdapter(new TextSubTextAdapter(this, Common.physConstants));`
As long as I have a limited set of elements, It works great, because I don't need to scroll. However, when I add enough elements, after scrolling, the items swap their positions, like this:

[image: Normal view][image: All hell breaks loose]

I suspect that this behavior is due to me calling `mCategories.get(position)`. Because the Views are never kept in the background and Android regenerates them every time, I never get the same item, as `position` will rarely have the same value.

Is there a way to get a constant id, which could allow me to get items with fixed positions ? I tried to use getItemID, but I do not understand how to implement it.

Note: Every string comes from a strings.xml file. They are never compared, and instanciated once, at startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll your list Android dynamically reuses the Views which scroll out of the screen. These convertViews don't have the content which should be at this position yet. You have to set that manually.

```
  View view;
  if (convertView == null)
  {
      LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      view = li.inflate(R.layout.text_sub, null);
  }
  else 
  {
      view = convertView;
  }
  TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.mainText);
  tv.setText(mCategories.get(position).first);

  TextView desc = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.subText);
  desc.setText(Html.fromHtml(mCategories.get(position).second));

  return view;
```

Comment: The concept is called Flyweight pattern, for anyone interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

Comment: Indeed, thank you. I've been looking everywhere but here, even though I knew that views were recycled. Hit me on the head.